# Scroll View and Toolbar

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, scrollview, toolbar

In Xcode 6, I am designing an app whose view has a scroll view and a toolbar. However, when I run my app in iOS Simulator, the toolbar stays where it was placed in interface builder and does not stay directly at the bottom as I scroll. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you placed the toolbar inside the scroll view?  If so, you will want to move it outside of the scroll view and anchor it instead at the bottom of the parent view.  Then you will want to reduce the size of your scroll view so that it does not get cut off by the toolbar.